C segfault question: if one of two inputs is null, return the other
I have a function that takes two strings and returns another string (if you must know, its my implementation of strjoin).
Now, I want to make it so that if one of the input strings is NULL, it will return the other string.
The most immediate way I figured is simply
if (!str1)
    return (str2);
if (!str2)
    return (str1);

But then I thought, let's go fancier, let's try to save a few lines and learn something in the process. So I figured there must be some operator whose result is whichever one of the two values is not zero, and I happened upon the bitwise OR operator (|).
When I tried to implement the following code, it said that these operators only work on integer type values, which kinda makes sense, I guess, but I'd like to know if there is a way to do this same exact thing with non-integers :)
if (!(str1 && str2))
    return (str1 | str2)
// error: expression must have integral type C/C++(31)

Now, because the problem was the data type, I figured I'll just typecast the shit out it. So I changed it into
if (!(str1 && str2))
    return ((char *)((int)str1 | (int)str2))
// segfault 

It's not pretty, but I figured it would work somehow. What happened was actually a segfault! But I honestly cannot explain why this would result in a segfault O_o Can someone explain?
EDIT: I know I could also use the ternary operator, but in my school it is forbidden :(
EDIT2: FYI I understand that everything about what I'm trying to do is not a good idea and I would never try this in real code. Please understand this is for educational purposes and I'm simply trying to explore possibilities, because that is how people learn.

You do know that the | operator is the bitwise OR operation? That is creates a completely new value that is not going to be the correct pointer to any of the variables?

The size of a pointer is not necessarily the same as the size of an int. You can use intptr_t, but I would definitely avoid this kind of "optimization". Let the compiler do its job.

"Now, because the problem was the data type" The main problem is that you want to do some crazy BS to a pointer.  Bitwise operations are not defined for pointers. BTW: Pointers can be larger than int. If you really want to win the prize for worst code, you need to use uintptr_t at least.

sizeof (int) is the same as sizeof (char*) in your implementation? Anyway, what you're trying to do is ill-advised!

As a simple workaround, how about something like return str1 ? str1 : str2;?

I see, I forgot that the sizes of the data types were different, I guess that explains the segfault! But my pointers do have the same size as long, so maybe I could do it by casting to long rather than int?

@CabtheKid Size is implementation defined. A pointer may not fit into a long. Again, you can use intptr_t, but please do not try to outsmart your compiler, you’ll fail and just make your code unreadable.

Note that saving lines of source code does not necessarily correspond to smaller or faster object code. And while it conserves screen real estate for displaying your code, it may take more of your time to understand what your code is doing when you come back and try to read it - or someone else tries to deal with it.

Doing a bitwise OR between two pointers will give you something that is neither the first nor the second pointer. It doesn't matter how you cast or convert the pointers or the resulting value.

Aside: I don't know how your strjoin() is specified, but you state "returns another string". The snippet you posted violates that, it returns a pre-existing string. Memory management is an issue here. If your fcn is expected to return another string, it must dynamically allocate it and the caller has the responsibility to de-allocate it. This code makes ownership ambiguous and renders the implementation unusable as the caller will be unable to determine what it has the responsibility to free.

@CabtheKid if (!str1) is a test if the pointer is not a null pointer.  A test for zero is something else as pointers are not just simply integers when testing with !.

@chux-ReinstateMonica Could you explain further? I'm under the impression that a null pointer is defined as a "null pointer constant cast to pointer type", and that a null pointer constant is defined as "any integer expression that evaluates to 0".  But I don't see how that makes a difference for testing with the ! operator.

@CabtheKid <the impression that a null pointer is defined as a "null pointer constant cast to pointer type">.  No.  A null pointer constant cast to a pointer type is a null pointer, yet a null pointer can be formed in other implementation defined ways.  A --> B, does not mean B is only formed by A.

@CabtheKid A null pointer, cast to an integer, does not certainly form an integer of zero.  This makes (char *) ((int)str1 | (int)str2) a problem.


So I figured there must be some operator whose result is whichever one of the two values is not zero,…

There is no operator specifically for this. return str1 ? str1 : str2; is likely a good solution. Modern compilers are mostly good at optimization, and you should generally trust them absent an acute need for high performance or evidence the compiler is failing in a particular case.

return ((char *)((int)str1 | (int)str2))
… But I honestly cannot explain why this would result in a segfault

There are several reasons that could cause a segment fault. One is that int may be too short to represent all addresses in your C implementation, so information is lost in the conversions. Another is the missing ; could allow this to combine with code after the return to form an undesired expression. (There are some other technically possible reasons that are less likely in ordinary C implementations, such as a null pointer not producing zero when converted to int.)

But my pointers do have the same size as long, so maybe I could do it by casting to long rather than int?

When it is necessary to convert pointers to an integer type for some reason, use uintptr_t, declared in <stdint.h>. That type is designed for that purpose.

…  let's try to save a few lines and learn something in the process…

Do you have a shortage of lines in your equipment? Are there so few new-line characters available to you that you need to conserve them? We could take up a collection and send you some new-line characters.
Attempting to save lines of code is generally not a valuable goal. (It is not entirely unaligned with valuable goals, such as making code easy to read, aesthetic and comprehensible to humans, and so on, but these goals have a directly useful priority, and reducing lines of code is only a side effect.)

The reason why I'm trying to "save lines" is because my assignments have a mandatory "norm" that I must follow, otherwise they won't even be evaluated. It includes things like, max 25 lines per function and max 5 functions per file, and some assignments only allow you to submit a certain number of files. So for example, in this project I'm doing now, I only have 6 * 25 lines I can write on ¯_(ツ)_/¯
These two lines won't be the death of this particular assignment, but if I can learn such things they might come in handy for future projects where I don't have so much leeway...!

@CabtheKid If there really is a requirement that states that you must not use more than a specified number of lines, which is stupid IMHO, you can always just write the whole if (!str1) { return (str2); } if (!str2) { return (str1); } in a single line. As long as the syntax is correct nothing stops you from writing multiple expressions/statements on one line, even if it gets harder to read.

@AviBerger: Re “The ternary option, while immediately suggesting itself, would not work here”: You show this code: if (!(str1 && str2)) return (str1 | str2). The return str1 ? str1 : str2; I show would work in place of the return there.

@CabtheKid newlines in not syntactically significant. You could if you were perverse put all your code (other than preprocessor directives) on one line. Line count is a counter productive metric, it discourages commenting and leads to unreadable code.  Statement count and cyclometric-complexity are better metrics.  You may need to consider the credibility of this course, but if the assignment has a limit, then that might be considered how long a "model answer" should be.  If you are resorting to "tricks" to keep the line count down, then there is probably a simpler solution.

Ah, in place of the return only. You are right. My bad.

The problem with this:
if (!(str1 && str2))
    return ((char *)((int)str1 | (int)str2));

Is that an int is not necessarily the same size as a pointer.  This means that the cast loses part of the value of the pointer.
The uintptr_t type is an unsigned type that is guaranteed to allow conversions to and from pointer types while retaining the original pointer value, so use that instead.
if (!(str1 && str2))
    return ((char *)((uintptr_t)str1 | (uintptr_t)str2));

And of course, you shouldn't really be doing these types of conversions on pointers.  What you did originally is easier to read and understand, and compilers should be able to optimize it just fine.

Some one liners that do not use ?: and can even handle a null pointer that is not all zero bits.
if (str1 == NULL) return str2; if (str2 == NULL) return str1; 

if (!str1 || !str1) return (char *) (((!!str1)*(uintptr_t)str1) | ((!str1)*(uintptr_t)str2));

Why the 2nd one works.
A pointer cast to optional integer type uintptr_t and then cast back to the same type of pointer results in an equivalent pointer to the original (although not certainly the same bit pattern)- it round trips.
When at least one of the pointers is a null pointer, pointers are converted to a suitable integer type with the values: str1_as_an_integer and str2_as_an_integer.  As one of (!!str1) and (!str1) is 0 and the other is 1, the | of the 2 products is str1_as_an_integer or str2_as_an_integer.  Converting that back to a char * results in an equivalent pointer to either str1 or str2.
